# How to not allow people manually changing html form code and submit

Tags: php, forms, security, codeigniter

So I'm using codeigniter, and I've made form for submitting comment.

```
echo form_open(current_url()); // http://localhost/post/26
$textarea = array(
    'id' => 'comment_area',
    'name' => 'comment',
    'value' => set_value('comment'),
    'cols' => 35,
    'rows' => 5
);
echo form_textarea($textarea);
echo '<br />';
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Comment');
echo form_close();
```

So how you might guess this produce: `<form action="http://localhost/post/26" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

But there is the problem, that when I manually change using firebug action id to 25:

```
<form action="http://localhost/post/25" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

and submit -> it submits comment to 25th post, not 26th... So how can I defend my form tag from smth like this?

Comment: You can not prevent people from not changing the html form code. You just have to find a way to make sure that the right data is being passed to you. It's more of a design decision. Average people won't even look at your html code. People that can mess with it are most likely to do what you did. :-)

Comment: You can send HTTP POST requests without a formular (e.g. with http://www.requestmaker.com/). You absolutely need to validate on your side.

Comment: Just check whether the user is allowed to comment on the given post when you receive the request and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I'd say don't bother yourself with such a thing. If they have permission than just let them do it.

**Here's a little explanation (scenario) why you probably don't want to do that.**

Let's say from what you provided, the key produced is 30 thus you'd have a form such as

```
< form action="http://localhost/post/30" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Suppose you now create another post which becomes 31 thus you'd now also have a form such as

```
< form action="http://localhost/post/31" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Now suppose I am a user who comes and read the 30th post, I would click a link that is

```
localhost/post/30 (http of course)
```

Now you suggest me to read another post which is the 31st post, I would click a link that is

```
localhost/post/31
```

What if a more knowledgeable user is on the 30th post and decides to change 30 to 31? How then would you know if they click the link you provided or changed the value themselves? (HTTP referer can be worked around from what I heard).

All I can say is check if they have permission to post on that particular post, else just let them do it. I think stackoverflow does the same thing too. Check if the post exists and the user has the permission to post a comment on that post. Then let them do it, don't worry yourself about them submitting a comment from one post to another post trying to be hackers. That's not hacking, that's fooling around.

**Edit:**
To much work for something that is not even a security issue if you have permission and the post exists. I just check permission(could be a little complex) and the existance of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server side issue. You must prevent the code from being posted this way in server.
You can probably use HTTP Post method for this. Another trick could be to encrypt the post id in a way, or generate a unique id for each post each time it needs to be accessed and use it temporarily.

Comment: How it is used?? HTTP Post requests??